# Use LaTeX Listings to correctly detect and syntax highlight embedded code of a different language in a script

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting, listings

I have scripts that have one-liners or sort scripts from other languages within them.  How can I have LaTeX listings detect this and change the syntax formating language within the script?  This would be especially useful for awk within bash I believe.

Bash

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello world"

R --vanilla << EOF
# Data on motor octane ratings for various gasoline blends
x <- c(88.5,87.7,83.4,86.7,87.5,91.5,88.6,100.3,
95.6,93.3,94.7,91.1,91.0,94.2,87.5,89.9,
88.3,87.6,84.3,86.7,88.2,90.8,88.3,98.8,
94.2,92.7,93.2,91.0,90.3,93.4,88.5,90.1,
89.2,88.3,85.3,87.9,88.6,90.9,89.0,96.1,
93.3,91.8,92.3,90.4,90.1,93.0,88.7,89.9,
89.8,89.6,87.4,88.9,91.2,89.3,94.4,92.7,
91.8,91.6,90.4,91.1,92.6,89.8,90.6,91.1,
90.4,89.3,89.7,90.3,91.6,90.5,93.7,92.7,
92.2,92.2,91.2,91.0,92.2,90.0,90.7)
x
length(x)
mean(x);var(x)
stem(x)
EOF

perl -n -e '
@t = split(/\t/);
%t2 = map { $_ => 1 } split(/,/,$t[1]);
$t[1] = join(",",keys %t2);
print join("\t",@t); ' knownGeneFromUCSC.txt

awk -F'\t' '{
  n = split($2, t, ","); _2 = x
  split(x, _) # use delete _ if supported
  for (i = 0; ++i <= n;)
    _[t[i]]++ || _2 = _2 ? _2 "," t[i] : t[i]
  $2 = _2 
  }-3' OFS='\t' infile
```

Python

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
print "Hello World"
os.system("""
VAR=even;
sed -i "s/$VAR/odd/" testfile;
for i in `cat testfile` ;
do echo $i; done;
echo "now the tr command is removing the vowels";
cat testfile |tr 'aeiou' ' '
""")
```

UPDATE:
These are my current Listings settings in the preamble:

```
% This gives syntax highlighting in the python environment
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Code Listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code Listing}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{key}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\lstloadlanguages{Fortran,C++,C,[LaTeX]TeX,Python,bash,R, Perl}

\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{
  \lstset{
    language=python,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    otherkeywords={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 0, -, =, +, [, ], (, ), \{, \}, :, *, !},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    emph={class, pass, in, for, while, if, is, elif, else, not, and, or,
    def, print, exec, break, continue, return},
    emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
    emph={[2]True, False, None, self},
    emphstyle=[2]\color{key},
    emph={[3]from, import, as},
    emphstyle=[3]\color{blue},
    upquote=true,
    morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,
    rulesepcolor=\color{blue},#1
  }
}{}

\lstnewenvironment{bash}{%
  \lstset{%
    language=bash,
    otherkeywords={=, +, [, ], (, ), \{, \}, *},
    % bash commands from:
    %http://www.math.montana.edu/Rweb/Rhelp/00Index.html
    emph={addgroup,adduser,alias,
    ant,
    apropos,apt-get,aptitude,aspell,awk,
    basename,bash,bc,bg,break,builtin,bzip2,cal,case,cat,cd,cfdisk,chgrp,
    chkconfig,chmod,chown,chroot,cksum,clear,cmp,comm,command,continue,
    cp,cron,crontab,csplit,cut,date,dc,dd,ddrescue,declare,df,diff,diff3,
    dig,dir,dircolors,dirname,dirs,dmesg,du,echo,egrep,eject,enable,env,
    ethtool,eval,exec,exit,expand,expect,export,expr,false,fdformat,
    fdisk,fg,fgrep,file,find,fmt,fold,for,format,free,fsck,ftp,function,
    fuser,gawk,getopts,
    git,
    grep,groups,gzip,
    gunzip,
    ,hash,head,help,history,hostname,
    id,if,ifconfig,ifdown,ifup,import,install,
    java, java6, java_cur
    join,kill,killall,less,
    let,ln,local,locate,logname,logout,look,lpc,lpr,lprint,lprintd,
    lprintq,lprm,ls,lsof,make,man,mkdir,mkfifo,mkisofs,mknod,mmv,more,
    mount,mtools,mtr,mv,
    mysql,
    netstat,nice,nl,nohup,notify-send,
    noweb,noweave,
    nslookup,op,
    open,passwd,paste,pathchk,ping,pkill,popd,pr,printcap,printenv,
    printf,ps,pushd,pwd,quota,quotacheck,quotactl,ram,rcp,read,
    readarray,readonly,reboot,remsync,rename,renice,return,rev,rm,rmdir,
    rsync,scp,screen,sdiff,sed,select,seq,set,sftp,shift,shopt,shutdown,
    sleep,slocate,sort,source,split,ssh,strace,su,sudo,sum,
    svn, svn2git,
    symlink,sync,
    tail,tar,tee,test,time,times,top,touch,tr,traceroute,trap,true,
    tsort,tty,type,ulimit,umask,umount,unalias,uname,unexpand,uniq,
    units,
    unrar,
    unset,unshar,until,useradd,usermod,users,uudecode,uuencode,
    vdir,vi,vmstat,watch,wc,Wget,whereis,which,while,who,whoami,write,
    zcat},
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,
  }
}{}

\lstnewenvironment{latexCode}[1]{\lstset{language=[latex]tex} \lstset{#1}}{}

\lstnewenvironment{Rcode}{
  \lstset{%
    language={R},
    basicstyle=\small,                  % print whole listing small
    keywordstyle=\color{black},         % style for keyword
    % Function list from:
    % http://www.math.montana.edu/Rweb/Rhelp/00Index.html
    emph={abbreviate, abline,
    abs, acos, acosh, all, all.names,
    all.vars, anova, anova.glm, anova.lm, any,
    aperm, append, apply, approx, approxfun,
    apropos, Arg, args, Arithmetic, array,
    arrows, as.array, as.call, as.character, as.complex,
    as.data.frame, as.double, as.expression, as.factor, asin,
    asinh, as.integer, as.list, as.logical, as.matrix,
    as.na, as.name, as.null, as.numeric, as.ordered,
    as.qr, as.real, assign, as.ts, as.vector,
    atan, atan2, atanh, attach, attr,
    attributes, autoload, .AutoloadEnv, axis, backsolve,
    barplot, beta, binomial, box, boxplot,
    boxplot.stats, break, browser, bw.bcv, bw.sj,
    bw.ucv, bxp, c, .C, call,
    cat, cbind, ceiling, character, charmatch,
    chisq.test, chol, chol2inv, choose, class,
    class<-, codes, coef, coefficients, coefficients.glm,
    coefficients.lm, co.intervals, col, colnames, colors,
    colours, Comparison, complete.cases, complex, Conj,
    contour, contrasts, contr.helmert, contr.poly, contr.sum,
    contr.treatment, convolve, cooks.distance, coplot, cor,
    cos, cosh, count.fields, cov, covratio,
    crossprod, cummax, cummin, cumprod, cumsum,
    curve, cut, D, data, data.class,
    data.entry, dataentry, data.frame, data.matrix, dbeta,
    dbinom, dcauchy, dchisq, de, debug,
    delay, demo, de.ncols, density, deparse,
    de.restore, deriv, deriv.default, deriv.formula, de.setup,
    detach, deviance, deviance.glm, deviance.lm, device,
    Devices, dev.off, dexp, df, dfbetas,
    dffits, df.residual, df.residual.glm, df.residual.lm, dgamma,
    dgeom, dget, dhyper, diag, diff,
    digamma, dim, dim<-, dimnames, dimnames<-,
    dlnorm, dlogis, dnbinom, dnchisq, dnorm,
    do.call, dotplot, double, dpois, dput,
    drop, dt, dump, dunif, duplicated,
    dweibull, dyn.load, edit, effects.glm, effects.lm,
    eigen, else, emacs, end, environment,
    environment<-, eval, exists, exp, expression,
    Extract, factor, family, family.glm, fft,
    finite, fitted, fitted.values, fitted.values.glm, fitted.values.lm,
    fivenum, fix, floor, for, formals,
    format, formatC, format.default, formula.default, formula.formula,
    formula.terms, .Fortran, frame, frequency, function,
    Gamma, gamma, gaussian, gc, gcinfo,
    get, getenv, gl, glm, glm.control,
    glm.fit, .GlobalEnv, graphics.off, gray, grep,
    grid, gsub, hat, heat.colors, help,
    hist, hsv, identify, if, ifelse,
    Im, image, \%in\%, influence.measures, inherits,
    integer, interactive, .Internal, inverse.gaussian, invisible,
    invisible, IQR, is.array, is.atomic, is.call,
    is.character, is.complex, is.data.frame, is.double, is.environment,
    is.expression, is.factor, is.function, is.integer, is.language,
    is.list, is.loaded, is.logical, is.matrix, is.na,
    is.name, is.null, is.numeric, is.ordered, is.qr,
    is.real, is.recursive, is.single, is.ts, is.unordered,
    is.vector, lapply, lbeta, lchoose, legend,
    length, LETTERS, letters, levels, levels<-,
    lgamma, .lib.loc, .Library, library, library.dynam,
    license, lines, lines.default, list, lm,
    lm.fit, lm.influence, lm.wfit, load, locator,
    log, log10, log2, Logic, logical,
    lower.tri, lowess, ls, ls.diag, lsfit,
    lsf.str, ls.print, ls.str, .Machine, Machine,
    machine, macintosh, mad, match, match.arg,
    match.call, matlines, mat.or.vec, matplot, matpoints,
    matrix, max, mean, median, menu,
    methods, min, missing, Mod, mode,
    mode<-, model.frame, model.frame.default, model.matrix, model.matrix.default,
    month.abb, month.name, mtext, mvfft, NA,
    na.action, na.action.default, na.fail, names, na.omit,
    nargs, nchar, NCOL, ncol, next,
    NextMethod, nextn, nlevels, nlm, [.noquote,
    noquote, NROW, nrow, NULL, numeric,
    objects, on.exit, optimize, options, order,
    ordered, outer, pairs, palette, par,
    parse, paste, pbeta, pbinom, pcauchy,
    pchisq, pentagamma, pexp, pf, pgamma,
    pgeom, phyper, pi, pictex, piechart,
    plnorm, plogis, plot, plot.default, plot.density,
    plot.ts, plot.xy, pmatch, pmax, pmin,
    pnbinom, pnchisq, pnorm, points, points.default,
    poisson, polygon, polyroot, postscript, ppoints,
    ppois, pretty, print, print.anova.glm, print.anova.lm,
    print.data.frame, print.default, print.density, print.formula, print.glm,
    print.lm, print.noquote, print.plot, print.summary.glm, print.summary.lm,
    print.terms, print.ts, proc.time, prod, prompt,
    prompt.default, prop.test, provide, .Provided, ps.options,
    pt, punif, pweibull, q, qbeta,
    qbinom, qcauchy, qchisq, qexp, qf,
    qgamma, qgeom, qhyper, qlnorm, qlogis,
    qnbinom, qnchisq, qnorm, qpois, qqline,
    qqnorm, qqplot, qr, qr.coef, qr.fitted,
    qr.Q, qr.qty, qr.qy, qr.R, qr.resid,
    qr.solve, qr.X, qt, quantile, quasi,
    quit, qunif, quote, qweibull, rainbow,
    .Random.seed, range, rank, rbeta, rbind,
    rbinom, rcauchy, rchisq, Re, readline,
    read.table, real, rect, remove, rep,
    repeat, replace, require, resid, residuals,
    residuals.glm, residuals.lm, return, rev, rexp,
    rf, rgamma, rgb, rgeom, rhyper,
    RLIBS, rlnorm, rlogis, rm, rnbinom,
    rnchisq, rnorm, round, row, row.names,
    rownames, rpois, rstudent, rt, runif,
    rweibull, sample, sapply, save, save.plot,
    scale, scan, sd, segments, seq,
    sequence, sign, signif, sin, sinh,
    sink, solve, solve.qr, sort, source,
    spline, splinefun, split, sqrt, start,
    stem, stop, storage.mode, storage.mode<-, str,
    str.data.frame, str.default, strheight, stripplot, strsplit,
    structure, strwidth, sub, Subscript, substitute,
    substr, substring, sum, summary, summary.glm,
    summary.lm, svd, sweep, switch, symbol.C,
    symbol.For, symnum, sys.call, sys.calls, sys.frame,
    sys.frames, sys.function, sys.nframe, sys.on.exit, sys.parent,
    sys.parents, system, system.date, system.time, t,
    table, tabulate, tan, tanh, tapply,
    tempfile, terms, terms.default, terms.formula, terms.terms,
    terrain.colors, tetragamma, text, time, title,
    topo.colors, trace, traceback, trigamma, trunc,
    ts, tsp, t.test, typeof, unclass,
    undebug, unique, uniroot, unlink, unlist,
    untrace, update, update.formula, update.glm, update.lm,
    upper.tri, UseMethod, var, vector, Version,
    version, vi, warning, weighted.mean, weights.lm,
    while, window, windows, write, x11,
    xedit, xemacs, xinch, xor, xy.coords,
    yinch},                             % define a list of word to emphasis
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,   % define the way to emphase
    showspaces=false,                   % show the space in code, or not
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,              % style of the string (like "hello word")
    showstringspaces=false,             % show the space in string, on not #1
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,
    tabsize=2,                          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    breaklines=true,                    % sets automatic line breaking
    breakatwhitespace=false,            % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  }
}{}

\lstnewenvironment{Perl}{
  \lstset{%
    language={perl},
    basicstyle=\small,                  % print whole listing small
    keywordstyle=\color{black},         % style for keyword
    emph={% From http://www.sdsc.edu/~moreland/courses/IntroPerl/docs/manual/pod/perlfunc.html
    -X, run, abs, absolute, accept, accept, alarm, schedule, atan2, 
    arctangent, bind, binds, binmode, prepare, bless, create, caller, 
    get, chdir, change, chmod, changes, chomp, remove, chop, remove, 
    chown, change, chr, get, chroot, make, close, close, closedir, close, 
    connect, connect, continue, optional, cos, cosine, crypt, one-way, 
    dbmclose, breaks, dbmopen, create, defined, test, delete, deletes, 
    die, raise, do, turn, dump, create, each, retrieve, endgrent, be, 
    endhostent, be, endnetent, be, endprotoent, be, endpwent, be, 
    endservent, be, eof, test, eval, catch, exec, abandon, exists, test, 
    exit, terminate, exp, raise, fcntl, file, fileno, return, flock, 
    lock, fork, create, format, declare, formline, internal, getc, get, 
    getgrent, get, getgrgid, get, getgrnam, get, gethostbyaddr, get, 
    gethostbyname, get, gethostent, get, getlogin, return, getnetbyaddr, 
    get, getnetbyname, get, getnetent, get, getpeername, find, getpgrp, 
    get, getppid, get, getpriority, get, getprotobyname, get, 
    getprotobynumber, get, getprotoent, get, getpwent, get, getpwnam, 
    get, getpwuid, get, getservbyname, get, getservbyport, get, 
    getservent, get, getsockname, retrieve, getsockopt, get, glob, 
    expand, gmtime, convert, goto, create, grep, locate, hex, convert, 
    import, patch, int, get, ioctl, system-dependent, join, join, keys, 
    retrieve, kill, send, last, exit, lc, return, lcfirst, return, 
    length, return, link, create, listen, register, local, create, 
    localtime, convert, log, retrieve, lstat, stat, m//, match, map, 
    apply, mkdir, create, msgctl, SysV, msgget, get, msgrcv, receive, 
    msgsnd, send, my, declare, next, iterate, no, unimport, oct, convert, 
    open, open, opendir, open, ord, find, pack, convert, package, 
    declare, pipe, open, pop, remove, pos, find, print, output, printf, 
    output, prototype, get, push, append, q/STRING/, singly, qq/STRING/, 
    doubly, quotemeta, quote, qw/STRING/, quote, qx/STRING/, backquote, 
    rand, retrieve, read, fixed-length, readdir, get, readlink, 
    determine, recv, receive, redo, start, ref, find, rename, change, 
    require, load, reset, clear, return, get, reverse, flip, rewinddir, 
    reset, rindex, right-to-left, rmdir, remove, s///, replace, scalar, 
    force, seek, reposition, seekdir, reposition, select, reset, semctl, 
    SysV, semget, get, semop, SysV, send, send, setgrent, prepare, 
    sethostent, prepare, setnetent, prepare, setpgrp, set, setpriority, 
    set, setprotoent, prepare, setpwent, prepare, setservent, prepare, 
    setsockopt, set, shift, remove, shmctl, SysV, shmget, get, shmread, 
    read, shmwrite, write, shutdown, close, sin, return, sleep, block, 
    socket, create, socketpair, create, sort, sort, splice, add, split, 
    split, sprintf, formatted, sqrt, square, srand, seed, stat, get, 
    study, optimize, sub, declare, substr, get, symlink, create, syscall, 
    execute, sysread, fixed-length, system, run, syswrite, fixed-length, 
    tell, get, telldir, get, tie, bind, time, return, times, return, 
    tr///, transliterate, truncate, shorten, uc, return, ucfirst, return, 
    umask, set, undef, remove, unlink, remove, unpack, convert, unshift, 
    prepend, untie, break, use, load, utime, set, values, return, vec, 
    test, wait, wait, waitpid, wait, wantarray, get, warn, print, write, 
    print, y///, transliterate},        % define a list of word to emphasis
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,   % define the way to emphase
    showspaces=false,                   % show the space in code, or not
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,              % style of the string (like "hello word")
    showstringspaces=false,             % show the space in string, on not #1
    commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,
    tabsize=2,                          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    breaklines=true,                    % sets automatic line breaking
    breakatwhitespace=false,            % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  }
}{}



\lstnewenvironment{plaintext}{
  \lstset{
    tabsize=2,                          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    breaklines=true,                    % sets automatic line breaking
    breakatwhitespace=false,            % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
  }
}{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost certainly easier to modify the Bash/Python highlighters than to write a context-sensitive highlighter.  I'm guessing that just adding the keywords to the other highlighters should give acceptable results.

Modifying Pygments doesn't look too difficult, from Pygments' [Write your own lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/) documentation.

Comment: +1 This seems like an idea that could be used to create an answer.  However, if I use pygments rather than listings would I be able to compile my document in something like LatexLabs without using a CLSI?

Comment: Hmm... I'm wondering whether there's some way use some kind of command like this:
escapeinside={perl -n -e '}{')}
with a separate perl environment that applies to it.

Comment: @D W: Latexlabs?  CLSI?  This doesn't sound like the original question!  IIRC, adding keywords to listings isn't hard: they're all together in some sort of list, but if you want to do something more complex, Pygments/Minted is much easier.  But if you *have* to use the Tex engine...

Comment: Hi Charles, I didn't mean to offend, I only mentioned LatexLabs to explain why the original question asked for a Listings solution.  I have added keywords to listings before and I have now attached a section of my current preamble.  As you can see each language seems to have a bunch of keywords and eventually I will further tailor the syntax highlighting and colouring to each language. That's why I was wondering whether there was a more proper solution than simply combining the keywords without giving up on using LatexLabs (ie. using listings).

Comment: @D W: Certainly no offence, rather surprise: you mentioned Listings in the question, but didn't indicate your extraordinary constraint.  I'm curious about actual use cases for the CLSI: Latex-based web applications should be able to run their own Tex engines.  I guess it's something to do with building web applications on top of other latex-based web applications.

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned CLSI, that just complicates the conversation, I am not doing anything with CLSI.  My only constraint is that the solution work with LatexLabs or some other online latex compiler.  This means no extra installations such as pygments as far as I know.

Comment: @D W: You can use \write18 from within Tex to invoke other programs, and then read in their output.  It's a security hole, but it's feasible.

Comment: Hi Charles thanks again for the comment.  I think I'm not explaining myself well.  I want to be able to compile my latex document with an online latex compiler that already exists, such as LatexLab - http://docs.latexlab.org/docs.  I do not have my own LatexLab running on my own server.  I can only use what latexlab.org enables plus additional style sheets.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is a feasible solution for someone.  I may be asking another question soon about how to get the \vsplit to do page breaking with the dual-line translation, ideally a minimal working example.  Perhaps you can help me out at that time.  I took a look at Tex by Topic but still can't get it.  I'm a LaTeX newb.